# DataGridView retaining old columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't quite seem to figure this one out.
I'm using a datagridview in VS2013. I've got a simple script to pull tables and update the grid view. It seems to work fine except that the datagridview seems to be appending the columns instead of replacing them with the new ones.

I've looked around for hours and have tried many remedies. Perhaps you can help?

Here's the code I use thus far:

```
public CentralStation(MySqlConnection _myConnection)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myConnection = _myConnection;
    myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    myCommand = new MySqlCommand(" ", myConnection);
    myDataTable = new DataTable();
    myBinder = new BindingSource();

    PopulateTableSelection();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tcpro." + this.tableMenuList.Text + ";";
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
        myDataTable.Clear();
        myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        myBinder.DataSource = null;
        myBinder.DataSource = myDataTable;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = myBinder;
        myAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using parameters in your `SQL` query in your code to prevent `SQL` injections.

Comment: I hate to bother since it's off topic but could you provide an example?

Comment: @DonaldCrockettPerry, here is the link on how to use parameters. Also, it's recommended to use `using` statement in your query. Read more. http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Answer (score 1):

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tcpro." + this.tableMenuList.Text + ";";
```

`myCommand` selects data from different db tables, right? those tables have different columns

`myAdapter` fills the same table

```
myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
```

data adapter doesn't clear rows and you need `myDataTable.Clear();` for that

so data adapter doesn't clear columns and you need clear them too:

```
myDataTable.Clear();
myDataTable.Columns.Clear();
```

it is not datagridview fault